# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’

Tags: for-loop, rbind, xlconnect

I am trying to combine a certain part of 51 Excel files by suing 'for' loops and 'rbind' codes.

files are:

```
 [1] "savedrecs-10.xls" "savedrecs-11.xls" "savedrecs-12.xls"
 [4] "savedrecs-13.xls" "savedrecs-14.xls" "savedrecs-15.xls"
 [7] "savedrecs-16.xls" "savedrecs-17.xls" "savedrecs-18.xls"
[10] "savedrecs-19.xls" "savedrecs-20.xls" "savedrecs-21.xls"
[13] "savedrecs-22.xls" "savedrecs-23.xls" "savedrecs-24.xls"
[16] "savedrecs-25.xls" "savedrecs-26.xls" "savedrecs-27.xls"
[19] "savedrecs-28.xls" "savedrecs-29.xls" "savedrecs-30.xls"
[22] "savedrecs-31.xls" "savedrecs-32.xls" "savedrecs-33.xls"
[25] "savedrecs-34.xls" "savedrecs-35.xls" "savedrecs-36.xls"
[28] "savedrecs-37.xls" "savedrecs-38.xls" "savedrecs-39.xls"
[31] "savedrecs-4.xls"  "savedrecs-40.xls" "savedrecs-41.xls"
[34] "savedrecs-42.xls" "savedrecs-43.xls" "savedrecs-44.xls"
[37] "savedrecs-45.xls" "savedrecs-46.xls" "savedrecs-47.xls"
[40] "savedrecs-48.xls" "savedrecs-49.xls" "savedrecs-5.xls" 
[43] "savedrecs-50.xls" "savedrecs-51.xls" "savedrecs-52.xls"
[46] "savedrecs-53.xls" "savedrecs-54.xls" "savedrecs-6.xls" 
[49] "savedrecs-7.xls"  "savedrecs-8.xls"  "savedrecs-9.xls"
```

I already combined several other files as following:

```
articles1_10 <- read_excel(path="savedrecs.xls", sheet="savedrecs (2)", col_names=TRUE)
articles11_20 <- read_excel(path="savedrecs-2.xls", sheet="savedrecs", col_names=TRUE)
articles21_30 <- read_excel(path="savedrecs-3.xls", sheet="savedrecs", col_names=TRUE)
articles1_30 <- rbind(articles1_10, articles11_20, articles21_30)
articles1_30
write.csv(articles1_30, "articles1_30.csv")
```

For combining the 51 files, I was suggested to use the following code:

```
list <- list.files(pattern = ".xls")
for (i in 1:length(list)){

    name <- paste0("savedrecs",i) 
    path<-paste0("savedrecs-",i,".xls") 
    table=rbind(table,assign(name,readWorksheet(path, sheet = "savedrecs",startRow = 30,endRow = 39,startCol = 1,endCol = 139,header = FALSE)))

}
```

However, an error message like below follows after running the code.

**Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’**

I installed the related packages, which are:

```
library (rJava)
library (xlsxjars)
library (xlsx)
library (stringr)
library (readxl)
library (XLConnectJars)
library (XLConnect)
```

What does the aforementioned error message mean? What else can I combine the 51 files?